# Get value by two criterias on excel

Tags: excel

I want to get the last record in excel based on some criteria

Example

[image]

[image]

I need to get **ORDER_ID**, **DATE_IN**, **SKU**, **NAME** of first table

I'm using VLOOKUP but i need to use 2 conditions

The **DATE_IN** need to be the **MAX Older or Equal** **DATE_OUT** and **SKU** is equal.

How can i do that?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Remember that SO is not a code writing service but rather a forum to get help with your code. Also can you include in your result screenshot what values you are expecting to be populated. Any reason why you have SKU doubled on your second table? "The DATE_IN need to be the MAX Older or Equal DATE_OUT" this is very confusing. The oldest date would be the minimum (dates go up). Also when you saying equal DATE_OUT do you mean that it cannot be higher than the date out (can't ship what you don't have)?

Comment: Google for index/match with multiple criteria. I'm pretty sure that's exactly what you need